# Java - Best way to go about collecting PAST values

Tags: java, performance, swing, keyevent

I have a simple Mario game and have key events that decide different animations and movements of the player.

They are:

- Move Left
- Move Right
- Jump Left
- Jump Right

As you can imagine, the player will only be able to play the jump right animation if he is moving right and is/has pressed the jump button

[image]

The issue I have come across is that only 1 key value may be sent at once. This makes if statements with `&&` conditions useless.

Here was the code that did not work:

```
        if(key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
            if(distanceTraveled<300)dx=-5; else dx=-4;
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                player = jump_L_anim.getImage();
            else
                player = walk_L_anim.getImage();
         } else {
            if(distanceTraveled<300)dx=5; else dx=4;
            if(key == KeyEvent.VK_UP)
                player = jump_R_anim.getImage();
            else
                player = walk_R_anim.getImage();
        }
```

Simple enough, I realized that there are solutions to this and began attempting to figure out the key pressed before the current one.(this key could not be equal to the one currently pressed).

---

This would allow an if statement such as

```
if key==right    &&     lastKey == up
    run jump_R animation
```

---

I managed to be able to grab the last key, but not the last key that was not a repeat.

I felt really confused and decided to watch [this missile guidance for dummies video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8e1ktRjeOuI). That made me even more confused, In my boring accounting class I figured out the solution must be to store all previous values in an array, then I would loop through the values from the last to the beginning. I would continue this until the numbers would not continue. The number where the repetition stops is the last value i am looking for.

For anyone confused by this take a look at these console readings of key movements

```
48
48
48
49
49
49
49
47
47
47
```

The number I am looking for in this situation is 49. That is because it was the last key pressed that is not the current key.

Is my logic behind this issue correct? How would you solve this issue? I prefer not working with arrays if there is a simple variable only solution available. I am looking for the fastest and most efficient logic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps you can store which keys are held down at the moment into an HashSet, and the if statement would be something like:

```
if (keyCodeSet.contains(x) && keyCodeSet.contains(y))
```

where x and y are the key numbers you want.  When the keys are released, you simply remove them from the set.

Comment: A `Map` would be a better object for this.

Comment: yes but to gather the keys currently held down I would have to check the last values, keyEvents are only sent one at a time.

Comment: Yes, you might have to check the last values; how about adding the key code to the list before you run your logic for when the key is pressed down?  That way, the list will have the most up-to-date values before you check if both keys (or three, four, etc.) are pressed.

Comment: Alright, I like your logic. This allows for nice key combinations that do not ruin the patterns. Thank you

Comment: I'd consider a `Set` over `List`, but other wise the concept is sound +1

Comment: I agree, a set would be better.  I will revise the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You should keep track of when the keys are released.  If up is never released, you know it's still being held.  If right is never released, you know it's still being held.  Each update, you can check if both are down and react accordingly.

Comment: but what if someone is holding three keys?

Comment: @user2907910 that's up to you.  Can you give me a more concrete example of your concern?

Comment: I'm not sure, I have a feeling if three keys where held down the first key clicked would be ignored because you would overwrite the last ones. The second key would also be ignored unless I managed to store it and check it

Answer (score 0):

It's actually totally simple:

- Listen to both `keyPressed` and `keyReleased`
- use a `Set<Key>`<sup>1</sup> or just 4 variable for the keys you're interested in
- when a key gets pressed set, add it to the set
- when a key gets released, remove it

On any key press, check if the other key is there. This way you can distinguish "Up+Right" from "Right+Up" if you want to.

---

<sup>1</sup> `Key` may be `Integer` or whatever representation you prefer.